# Connecting to SSH using a bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to write a bash script to make things faster. Is it not possible to connect to the server with the code below in a bash script? I can't make it work, even though it works in the terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
echo "Starting connection script"
sh -i /home/EC2_KEY_HEHE.pem ubuntu@ec2-IP.blabla.amazonaws.com
```

What I get when I run is a not found output for each line in the pem file,

```
$ /home/EC2_KEY_HEHE.pem: 1: /home/EC2_KEY_HEHE.pem: -----BEGIN: not found
$ /home/EC2_KEY_HEHE.pem: 1: /home/EC2_KEY_HEHE.pem: adsnaleAFemasdsdsdnds: not foundMadfdasfdasfnda;vonraada
...
```

Comment: Noticed you wrote "sh -i" in your script. Could it be that you simply made a typo? It should be "ssh -i". Note that "sh" is not same as "ssh".

Comment: Thank you. Oh my god. I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: :) Btw Kirill Chernyavskiy already noticed this and tried to help. Should we accept his answer? What do you think?

Comment: I didn't realize he was pointing that out. I thought he was talking about the -v tag. My bad. Yes, we better pick his answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some debug is needed.

Please change:

`ssh -i /home/EC2_KEY_HEHE.pem ubuntu@ec2-IP.blabla.amazonaws.com`

to:

```
 #!/bin/bash -x
 echo "Starting connection script"
 ssh -vi /home/EC2_KEY_HEHE.pem ubuntu@ec2-IP.blabla.amazonaws.com
```

does it produce an idea about the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the script `sh`, which is a shell (such as `bash`). Instead, use `ssh`:

```bash
ssh -i /home/EC2_KEY_HEHE.pem ubuntu@ec2-IP.blabla.amazonaws.com
```